# RODBC error connecting to Netezza: Can't open lib libnzodbc.so file not found

Tags: r

I'm unable to connect to a Netezza appliance within either R command line or Rstudio.  However, I am able to connect to the appliance using isql and nzodbcsql command line tools.

Here's my config so far in Redhat Linux:
1. unixODBC manager installed
2. User environment variables:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nz/lib64, where the Netezza library exists. Permissions on the directories are 755

NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=/common/odbc, where the ODBC config files are located. Permissions are also 755 at this location.
3. Ran "odbcinst -j" to check configuration of ODBC files:

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /common/odbc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /common/odbc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /common/odbc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /common/odbc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

4. Able to query Netezza using isql and nzodbcsql (select * from _v_dual will return 1 record). Let's pretend the ODBC DNS name is "testdsn"

---

Attempting to use RODBC in an R session:

```
library(RODBC)
z = odbcConnect("testdsn")
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=testdsn") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so' : file not found
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=testdsn") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

This error usually indicates that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set correctly. I know while I have it set on the command line, it's not set for R, so I set it in Renviron.site config file.

```
Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
[1] "/lib64:/usr/include:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/nz/lib64"
```

I have also run a ldd on the libnzodbc.so file, and am not seeing any linking problems:

```
system("ldd /usr/local/nz/lib64/libnzodbc.so")
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1fdce000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f26ede93000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f26edb91000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f26ed975000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f26ed771000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f26ee58a000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f26ed664000)
        libcom_err.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libcom_err.so.3 (0x00007f26ed561000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/local/nz/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f26ed41e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f26ee54c000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f26ed205000)
```

I'm able to query via the unixODBC and Netezza command line tools, but can't query via R or Rstudio.  As far as I can tell, I have the R environment variables set up correctly to find the library path, but it still can't find the file.  Does anyone know if I'm missing anything else?

R version: 3.4.4
Netezza driver version: 3.51
Rehat version: 7.6

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to get it working.  For some reason R seems to be ignoring the entries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Instead, I added the library location using ldconfig.  Once it was added there and loaded (verified by running ldconfig -p), I was able to query in R.

Comment: How did you configure it with ldconfig?